# Retrieving location of found text in array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, indexing

I have a large file that is loaded into an array and by using the `.Contains` method I check to see if the array contains a certain sub string.

After called the `.Contains` method is their a way for me to get the index of the found object(s).

Example:

```
Dim foo() As String = {"1","2","3"}
If foo.Contains("2") Then
   'return the index of the found number in this case 1
Else
   Return False
End If
```

Comment: In one case you want to return an integer, and in the other a boolean.  Array.IndexOf can give you the index of the item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried, [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx)

e.g

```
var i = Array.IndexOf(yourArray, "2");
```

Comment: thank you will accept your asap. Sometimes the simplest things get yo u stuck :)

Answer (score 2):

IndexOf will give you location of object in array. Use This:

```
  foo.IndexOf("2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
Dim foo() As String = {"1","2","3"}
Dim myIndex As Integer = Array.IndexOf(foo, "2")
```

It should return -1 if it is not in the array.